# How to make query request using ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

what command I should write in ExpressJS file just so that exposes a single HTTP endpoint (/api/search?symbol=$symbol&period=$period)

Working

```
    app.get('/api/search/', (req, res) => {
     res.send(req.query)
 })
```

Not working:

```
    app.get('/api/search?symbol=$symbol&period=$period', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.query)
})
```

Comment: Kindly post some of your code/efforts then only we can help.

Comment: Welcome to So. What have you tried so far??

Comment: You don’t have to explicitly specify the query params in express, just access it via req.query.symbol

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/api/search?symbol=$symbol&period=$period', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.query)
})
```

In place of this, you have to write below code

```
const note = require('../app/controllers/note.controller.js');
  // Create a new API CALL
    app.get('/comment/get', note.index); // In socket.controller.js i have function with the name of index 


//note.controller.js file code
exports.index = (req, res) => {
    var requestTime = moment().unix();

    req.body = req.query;

console.log(req.body); // you will able to get all parameter of GET request in it.

}
```

Let me know if i need to explain more about

And for sample code of express for API you can view this...

https://github.com/pawansgi92/node-express-rest-api-sample

Comment: I think there can be a simpler approach, as the question says: Write a simple web application (using ExpressJS) that exposes a single HTTP endpoint (/api/search?symbol=$symbol&period=$period)

Answer (score 0):

What *I think* you're looking for is this:

```
app.get('/api/search', (req, res) => {
    let symbol = req.query.symbol
    let period = req.query.period
})
```

So when you navigate to `/api/search?symbol=foo&period=bar`

`req.query.symbol` is "foo"
and `req.query.period` is "bar"

Comment: I have been assigned a task that says: Write a simple web application (using ExpressJS) that exposes a single HTTP endpoint (/api/search?symbol=$symbol&period=$period)